# Php page title or hyperlink to html url?

Tags: html

How I can set my php page title as

> www.ww.com/xyz_view.php?xyz_id=142-xyz-for-sell-at-xyz

to html url such as

> www.ww.com/748001-xyz-to-sell-at-xyz-south-faci.html

plz advice.

Comment: It is request URL not **page title**. Also, I assume you are talking about PHP which you did not specify. maybe this post can help? [Execute PHP from a .html File](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Using htaccess rewrite rule, you can do such a thing

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

Answer (score 0):

if your webserver is apache, you can use mod_rewrite

http://www.bloghash.com/2006/12/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

if not, tell us the name of your webserver software